# Scripts missing from most of my sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Most of my scripts have disappeared from my Google Spreadsheets. I'm still getting script failure notifications for my triggers and some of the scripts are still running even though there is no visible script there.

Comment: In the script editor try going to file > open and see if it is there

Comment: Are they [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=type:script) by any chance?

Comment: Looks that there is a related issue in the Google Apps Script Issue Tracker: [issue5831: Scripts disappeared from Spreadsheets](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5831)

Comment: Related: [Scripts disappeared from google sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120426/scripts-disappeared-from-google-sheet) (no answers at this time).